# How to fix square shaped in ggplot for an PDF report?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I want to fix my plot in RMarkdown (by using RStudio) such that it gets rendered as a square in a PDF report.

My RMarkdown script:

````
---
header-includes: \usepackage{graphicx}
output: 
    pdf_document:
        keep_tex: true
---

```{r results='hide', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)

minX <- min(iris$Sepal.Length) # 4.3
maxX <- max(iris$Sepal.Length) # 7.9
minY <- min(iris$Sepal.Width)  # 2.0
maxY <- max(iris$Sepal.Width)  # 4.4

# 7.9 - 4.3 = 3.6. Extend the y range by 0.5 * (3.6 - 2.4) = 0.6

minY <- minY - 0.6
maxY <- maxY + 0.6

scatter <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) 
scatter <- scatter + geom_point()
scatter <- scatter + xlim(minX, maxX)
scatter <- scatter + ylim(minY, maxY)
#scatter <- scatter + coord_fixed()
scatter
```
````

My PDF report is like this. This is clearly not a square:

[image]

If I uncomment the line for `coord_fixed()` in my R script, I'd get this:

[image]

Now, this is a square but it's wasting the horizontal space and it's very small. How to do it properly?

Comment: if you're happy with the figure format, then the size is just a matter of specifying a larger width in your knitr chunk.

Comment: @baptiste Can you please elaborate? I don't get quite get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell knitr to make bigger figures, e.g.

````
```{r width=7,out.width="7in"}
 ...
```
````